# pandas eval not supporting where

Tags: pandas

pandas eval is using numexpr, which supports the `where` function. Why pandas seems not to support it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,5]})
df.eval("where(a > 1, b ** 2, 2 * b)")

# -> ValueError: "where" is not a supported function
```

Any workaround? The only one I see is

```
df.eval("(a > 1) * (b ** 2) + (~(a > 1)) * (2 * b)")
```

but not very efficient. Other solution may be:

```
df.eval("cond = (a > 1)\n res= a * (b ** 2) + (~cond) * (2 * b)")
```

this may be more efficient, but it assigns two new columns to `df` which is not desiderable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generalisation of Hoang's answer. The idea is to use the DataFrame as a dict that numexpr can use to directly lookup the data. This allows any field in the DataFrame to be used in the expression without having to create a reference beforehand.

```
import numexpr as ne

# specify to numexpr to use the dataframe as a local dict
ne.evaluate('where(a>1, b**2, 2*b)', local_dict=df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve to native numexpr call:

```
a,b=df['a'],df['b']
ne.evaluate('where(a>1, b**2, 2*b)')
# 44.5 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Versus:

```
df.eval("(a > 1) * (b ** 2) + (~(a > 1)) * (2 * b)")
# 1.99 ms ± 47.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: is this copying memory in the first line?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra normally no.